# didBeginContact not called on fast moving sprite

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skphysicsworld

I have a game where a user is dragging around my main sprite. The main sprite collides with other sprites just fine except when the user drags the main sprite very quickly. Sometimes when the main sprite is moving quickly, the physics bodies just pass right through each other and the two sprites suddenly overlap. I have a breakpoint set that logs the hit count at didBeginContact, and it is not hit.

Is there a limit to how fast a sprite can move and still be covered by didBeginContact? Am I allowing the user to move the sprite faster than the game cycle can handle the collisions?

Again, when the sprite is moving at slow speeds, the physics are working perfectly.

Comment: If your sprite (ball) is moving at a speed of say x+50 and your collision object (wall) is only 20x wide then your ball will pass right over your wall in one frame without a collision taking place.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, these things are all calculated frame by frame.  You're probably moving the sprite so fast that its ending up on the other side of the screen in too few frames to count as a collision.  If someone is spastically moving their finger around it might not catch it.  You could put some kind of speed limit on the sprite or something.

Answer (score 1):

try to set physic body with `usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES`